# When I perform "rasa init" error: "failed to install native tensorflow runtime"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, rasa

When I perform "rasa init" operation it throws the following error: "failed to install native tensorflow runtime". I tried upgrading it to tensor flow =1.15 but rasa uses only tensorflow>2.1.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\Scripts\rasa.exe__main__.py", line 7, in 
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\rasa__main__.py", line 82, in main
    set_log_level(log_level)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 71, in set_log_level
    update_tensorflow_log_level()
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 107, in update_tensorflow_log_level
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 101, in 
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 40, in 
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\udays.conda\envs\chatbots\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: do you have vs c++ build tools installed?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. I fixed it by installing c++ build tool using the below link.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16